# 511 Command Not Permitted on a dead channel

Tags: asterisk

I have a problem with asterisk.

Version : asterisk 11.21.0

When I call to my server, I received message :

> 511 Command Not Permitted on a dead channel

Any `stream_file` or `agi->get_data` not response.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call already hanguped.

Calls in hanguped states have limited set of AGI commands availible. Not allowed any new dials, playback, any command which issues delays.